# How to deny empty array indexes in bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, sed

I wrote the bash like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
GAP=1
Out=$1
ResultFile=$2

len=`wc -l $Out | awk '{print $1}'`
eval "(COMMAND) &"
pid=$!

i=0
while kill -0 $pid; do
    if [ -N $Out ]; then
        newlen=`wc -l $Out | awk '{print $1}'`
        newlines=`expr $newlen - $len`
        tail -$newlines $Out > temp
        IP=( $(sed -n '<SomeThing>' temp) )
        host=${IP[$i]}
            echo "exit" | nc $host 23
            if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
                    (
                           <DoingSomeThing>

            ) | nc $host 23 1>>$ResultFile 2>&1
            fi
    len=$newlen
    let i++
    fi
sleep $GAP
done
```

When the command `IP=( $(sed -n '<SomeThing>' temp) )` is running in my bash maybe the result of `sed` command is nothing and maybe the output is `ip`. I want only when output of sed command get ip write it into array and when the output of sed is empty does not write it to array.

Thank you

Comment: -N file
              True if file exists and has been modified since it was last read.

Comment: Interestingly `man test` doesn't show it on OSX.

Comment: How about `man bash` ? :)

Comment: Thanks +1 for showing me use of `-N`

Comment: You probably don't want to use `eval`, and depending on what `COMMAND` is, probably completely unnecessary.

Comment: Yes you are right @chepner

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing your script right in many ways but about your question, the quick way is to store the output first on a variable:

```
SED_OUT=$(sed -n '<SomeThing>' temp)
[[ -n $SED_OUT ]] && IP=($SED_OUT) ## Would only alter IP if $SED_OUT has a value.
```

Comment: Welcome. And sure I won't mind but can you please explain what you really want to do with your script?

Comment: Pardon me ... I want handle my servers... because they are about 20 servers and hard to manage one by one...

Comment: But there is a problem...What is going to happen with `echo "exit" | nc $host 23` and other commands in loop? I want if output of sed is empty then don't check the `echo ...` and `if` states

Comment: Does IP get more than one hosts from "$OUT"?

Comment: It would actually be nice to have a snippet of $OUT so I could help you simplify extracting IP from it and help me understand what you really want to do with your code.